# How to find a graphical solution for extreme values using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I need to find the maxima and minima of a function. I managed this analytically with no problem, but now I need to show in a graphic the intersection of the functions.

My function is:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 - x*y + y^2 +3
```

And the restriction : `x^2 + 2*y^2 == 1`

Comment: Bad English is endemic here, so don't worry. But we try to get good _questions_. Please post the code you already tried!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: "Sorry for my bad english" <-- You can start by trying to use proper capitalization ("I" vs "i") and including some punctuation.  Yes, these things really make a difference in how easy it is to understand your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your title refers to Lagrange optimization, I'm guessing you're seeking to find the maximum and minimum of a function `f[x,y]` subject to a constraint `g[x,y]=0`.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 - x*y + y^2 + 3;

g[x_, y_] := x^2 + 2*y^2 - 1;

myConstraintEq = Solve[g[x, y] == 0, {x, y}] // Quiet;

Show[

  Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],

  Graphics3D[{
    {Red, PointSize[0.03], 
    Point[{x, y, f[x, y]} /. Last@FindMaximum[{f[x, y], g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]]}, 
    {Blue, PointSize[0.03], 
    Point[{x, y, f[x, y]} /. Last@FindMinimum[{f[x, y], g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]]}}],

  ParametricPlot3D[{
    {x, yy = y /. myConstraintEq[[1]], f[x, yy]}, 
    {x, yy = y /. myConstraintEq[[2]], f[x, yy]}}, 
    {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Green]

]
```

[image: Lagrange image]

Comment: Just an aesthetic comment: `{x, y, f[x, y]} /. Last@FindMaximum[{f[x, y], g[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]` is nicer :)

Comment: Yes...  More elegant.  I've changed the code accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have a tiny doubt if analytically i got 4 critical points the graphic should not display 4 points?

Comment: And maybe if it helps when asked the professors he told us use 3 variables like f[x,y,z] = z - f[x,y]. And sorry for no display the code T_T m still very noob in use the forum xD

Comment: There are likely four solutions where the derivative is zero, but only one MAXIMUM, one MINIMUM, and two INFLECTION POINTS.  You can see this if you plot just the green curve alone.

Answer (score 4):

This is a corrected version of poor quality post I originally posted.

This is to classify the extreme values using Lagrange multiplier method. The bordered Hessian for 2D case with one constraint is calculated. Projections onto x-z and y-z plane are used just to show the minima and maxima (local and global for constraint):

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 - x*y + y^2 + 3
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + 2*y^2
l[x_, y_, m_] := f[x, y] - m (g[x, y] - 1)
cp = Solve[Grad[l[x, y, m], {x, y, m}] == 0, {x, y, m}, Reals];
cph = N[{x, y, m} /. cp];
pnt = {#1, #2, f[#1, #2]} & @@@ cph;
p3 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6]];
pp = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t]/Sqrt[2], 
    f[Cos[t], Sin[t]/Sqrt[2]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
borhf[u_, v_, w_] := 
 Module[{gg = Grad[g[x, y], {x, y}], hs = D[l[x, y, m], {{x, y}, 2}]},
  Normal@SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 
       0, {1, 2} -> -gg[[1]], {1, 3} -> -gg[[2]], {2, 
        1} -> -gg[[1]], {3, 1} -> -gg[[2]], 
      Sequence @@ 
       Flatten@MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Table[{i, j}, {i, 2, 3}, {j, 2, 
            3}], hs}, 2]}, {3, 3}] /. {x -> u, y -> v, m -> w}]
class = Sign[-Det[#] & /@ (borhf @@@ cph)];
classt = Thread[{pnt, class}];
sort = SortBy[classt, #[[1, 3]] &];
max = sort[[1, 1]];
min = sort[[-1, 1]];
rules = {-1 :> Red, 1 :> Purple};
classp = class /. rules;
gp = GroupBy[classt, Last -> First];
g3 = Graphics3D[({#2 /. rules, PointSize[0.04], Point[#1]} & @@@ 
      sort)~Join~{PointSize[0.02], Yellow, Point[{min, max}]}];
sf[x_, r_] := Style[x, r /. rules];
grd = Grid[{{"Point", "Sign Det Bordered Hessian"}}~
    Join~({sf[#1, #2], sf[#2, #2]} & @@@ sort), Alignment -> Left, 
   Frame -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Kartika"}, 
   Background -> {None, {None, Yellow, None, None, Yellow}}];
pleg = PointLegend[{Purple, Purple, Red, Red}, {"Min", "Local Min", 
    "Local Max", "Max"}, 
   LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{PointSize[0.04], Purple, 
       Disk[{0, 0}, 0.2], PointSize[0.02], Yellow, 
       Disk[{0, 0}, 0.1]}], Automatic, Automatic, 
     Graphics[{PointSize[0.04], Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.2], 
       PointSize[0.02], Yellow, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.1]}]}];
im1 = Framed@
   Legended[Show[p3, pp, g3, ImageSize -> 300], 
    Placed[Column[{pleg, grd}], Below]]'
xz[t_] := {Cos[t], f[Cos[t], Sin[t]/Sqrt[2]]};
yz[t_] := {Sin[t]/Sqrt[2], f[Cos[t], Sin[t]/Sqrt[2]]};
pp1 = ParametricPlot[xz[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Epilog -> {{#2 /. rules, PointSize[0.04], Point[#1[[{1, 3}]]]} & @@@
       classt, {PointSize[0.02], Yellow, 
      Point[{min[[{1, 3}]], max[[{1, 3}]]}]}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {1.5, 4.5}}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLabel -> "Projection onto x-z plane", ImageSize -> 200];
pp2 = ParametricPlot[yz[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Epilog -> {{#2 /. rules, PointSize[0.04], Point[#1[[{2, 3}]]]} & @@@
       classt, {PointSize[0.02], Yellow, 
      Point[{min[[{2, 3}]], max[[{2, 3}]]}]}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {1.5, 4.5}}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLabel -> "Projection onto y-z plane", ImageSize -> 200];
im2 = Framed@Legended[Row[{pp1, pp2}], Placed[pleg, Below]]
```

[image]

[image]

Note:

You can plot f and constraint in one plot using `MeshFunctions`:

```
Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  MeshFunctions -> (#1^2 + 2 #2^2 &), Mesh -> {{1}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Blue], g3]
```

[image]